# An interesting geometry problem

Tags: geometry

In a  ΔMAP, on sides MA and AP, squares are drawn. If P and D are on the same side of AM;      and M,E lie  on opposite sides of AP. D and E are the centres of the squares on MA and AP respectively. Find the angle between MP and DE.
[image]

I have been trying to solve this problem since long time and I've been unable to do so. I have already found an approach using complex numbers but I want a pure geometry solution. The diagram was really complicated and visualising constructions were much harder. Would someone please help me to solve this question? Thanks for help .

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange. Write your questions clearly. Try to avoid to set pictures as your questions.

Comment: Hint: Triangles AMP and ADE are homothetic.

Comment: I think there isn't enough given, anything else about triangle MAP ?

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Actually, the two triangles are *similar*. Homotheticity is a slightly stronger property.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Thanks, you are right. And that is the next hint: figuring out which rotation makes those similar triangles into homothetic ones solves the problem ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Note 45 + ∠EAD + 45 = ∠PAM + 90 $\implies$ ∠EAD  = ∠PAM. Then, along with AM=$\sqrt2$ AD and AP=$\sqrt2$ AE, the triangle ADE and AMP are similar.

Since the sides AD and AE are at the 45-degrees with respect to AM and AP, respectively, the third side DE is also at the 45-degrees with respect to MP.

Comment: How does one get that $AM=\sqrt2AD$ and $AP=\sqrt2AE$?

Comment: @YiFan - AD and AE are half diagonals of the two squares.

Comment: thanks, I don't know how I didn't see that..

Comment: Thank you very much